# Как работает unsigned?

Tags: c, unsigned

Недавно начал изучать С и познакомился с таким классификатором как `unsigned`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    unsigned int a;
    a = -3;
    printf("%d", a + -10);
}
```

Выводится число `-13`. Почему? Ведь переменные с `unsigned` не содержат информацию о знаке?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113437/discussion-on-question-by-python-beginner---unsigned).

Comment: @Grundy, зачем перенёс? Это ж почти ответы были.

Comment: @Qwertiy, зачем почти, когда есть просто? :)

Comment: @Grundy, тут интереснее.

Comment: @Grundy, может такой подход к комментариям и порождает [такую ситуацию?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/10881/232)

Comment: @avp, ну так очевидно, если все пишут в комментариях - не пишут ответы, следовательно не получают прирост репутации ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Grundy, черт, побери! Это же хорошо объясняет наблюдаемое явление (хотя и не приближает нас к решению проблемы)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Смотрите, в чем дело. Эта программа содержит неопределенное поведение из-за несоответствия спецификаторов формата и фактических аргументов в вызове функции `printf`. Стандарт не налагает никаких ограничений на поведение программы, содержащей неопределенное поведение. Однако мы можем по-рассуждать, почему в вашем конкретном случае программа выводит `-13`.

---

> ```
> unsigned int a;
> a = -3;
> ```

Оператор `=` называется *simple assignment operator*. Вот, что происходит в строке с присваиванием:

1. Тип *assignment expression* (т. е. всего выражения `a = -3`) является типом выражения с левой стороны (т. е. типом `a` — `unsigned int`).
2. Выражение справа преобразуется в тип assignment expression и затем замещает значение в объекте, на который указывает операнд слева (т. е. `a`).

   Другими словами выражение справа типа `int` неявно преобразуется в тип `unsigned int`. По правилам значение конвертируется с помощью добавления к нему `UINT_MAX + 1`<sup>1, 2</sup>, согласно § 6.3.1.3 / 2<sup>3</sup>.

Т. е. в переменную `a` никогда не попадет значение `-3` типа `int`, оно будет неявно преобразовано в тип `unsigned int` перед присваиванием. А вот что получится в результате этого неявного преобразование зависит от значения `UINT_MAX`, которое само уже зависит от реализации. Другими словами, мы можем считать, что в `a` сейчас хранится `-3 + 1 + UINT_MAX`.

Далее — выражение `a - 10`. Здесь имеют место *usual arithmetic conversions* (§ 6.3.1.8), в ходе которых операнд `10` типа `signed int` преобразуется в `unsigned int`. Путем несложных подсчетов можно выяснить, что в итоге функции передается значение `(-3 + 1 + UINT_MAX) - 10`<sup>4</sup>.

Далее. При вызове функции с переменным числом аргументов (каковой и является `printf`) происходит процесс, который называется *default argument promotions* (§ 6.5.2.2 / 6), при котором каждый аргумент проходит преобразование в некоторый тип и только затем, в преобразованном виде, передается на вход функции. Согласно правилам таких преобразований аргумент `a` в данном случае не будет преобразован ни в какой другой тип, т. е. останется типа `unsigned int`.

Здесь возникает проблема: функция `printf` ожидает на входе тип `int` (потому что мы указали спецификатор `%d` в формате), но мы её на вход передаем тип `unsigned int`. Все, что произойдет далее зависит от того, <strike>как сложатся звезды</strike> как реализована функция `printf`.

Можем сделать некоторые предположения. Пусть `UINT_MAX` равно `4294967295` и на нашей платформе используется two's complement. Тогда в `printf` передается значение `(-3 + 1 + UINT_MAX) - 10`, что равно `4294967283`. Объектное представление беззнаковых целых в C — это просто их двоичная запись. В данном случае — это 4 байта `0xFFFFFFF3`. Если эти 4 байта интерпретировать как `int` в two's complement (что и вынуждена делать функция `printf` в нашем примере), то получится как раз `-13`.

---

<sup>1</sup> `UINT_MAX` — это в случае `unsigned int`.

<sup>2</sup> На этом, кстати, основан трюк с получением значения `UINT_MAX`: `unsigned int a = -1;`.

<sup>3</sup> Все ссылки в данном ответе предполагают рабочий черновик стандарта ISO/IEC 9899:202x (E) от 7-го июня 2019 года.

<sup>4</sup> Как правильно [заметил](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1182912/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-unsigned/1182969?noredirect=1#comment2058850_1182969) @wololo в комментариях, передается на самом деле `(-3 + 1 + UINT_MAX) + (-10 + 1 + UINT_MAX)`, т. к. `(int) -10` тоже подвергается преобразованию в `unsigned int`. На результат этот не повлияет и для простоты вычислений закроем глаза на этот нюанс.

Comment: "Далее — выражение `a - 10`". Но ведь выражение имеет вид `a + -10`. Преобразовать `10` в `unsigned int` — это совсем не то же самое, что преобразовать `-10` в `unsigned int`.

Comment: @wololo, точно, не заметил, спасибо! На самом деле ничего кардинально не изменится, просто добавится еще один integer promotion из-за § 6.5.3.3 / 3.

Comment: UB и ill-formed - разные вещи. Код в вопросе вызывает UB, но не является ill-formed.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, да, вы правы. Я тут посмотрел, в стандарте C вообще нет такого термина (видимо, он залез мне в голову из C++ и так там и остался :) ). Спасибо.

Comment: Уже не единожды замечал, что здесь в комментариях и ответах в printf иногда указывают знаковый спецификатор типа, но передают беззнаковый аргумент и наоборот. Наконец-то кто-то обратил внимание на ошибочность таких конструкций. Так что это вам спасибо. P.S. Хоть итоговый результат и не изменится, но слагаемые немного другие. К значению `(-3 + 1 + UINT_MAX)` прибавляется значение `(-10 + 1 + UINTMAX)`.

Comment: @wololo, да, спасибо, я добавил примечание на этот счет.